# Parse Hello World warning - A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I get the following error:

> Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main
>   thread.   Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

Code as follows:

```
- (IBAction)createButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    PFObject *demoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:
                            @"Demo"]; // 1
    [demoObject setObject:@"data value" forKey:@"dataColumn"]; // 2
    [demoObject save]; // 3
}
```

Comment: You can run that in background like [demoObj saveInBackground]; . This may help you :)

Comment: I have a quick question. I found a method called `[gameScore saveEventually];` that can be saved when the internet is not available and it saves to the parse cloud when it's back. But,  it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way,

```
 PFObject * demoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Demo"];
    demoObject[@"dataColumn"] = @"data value";

[demoObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
     {
         // take any action after saving.
}];
```